# org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate expected to be declared as @Bean and plain @Autowired throws error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I needed a RestTemplate object in my `@RestController` class "personController" so i declared it like below.

```
@Autowired
 private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

when i tried to use it im getting the below error
Field restTemplate in com.example.demo.api.PersonController required a bean of type `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` in your configuration.

To overcome the error,i declare a `@Bean` for restemplate like below in a config.java file and its working fine and not throwing any error.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate;
}
```

I am using a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` object in `@Service` class "personService" and i autowired it like below.

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

im able to use the objectmapper without declaring any bean for it and its working fine. 
I wanted to understand

1. Why objectmapper is working without bean but resttemplate is not
   working without bean and expecting a bean to be declared?
2. When to create a bean and when to simply use plain `@Autowired` without
   bean? how can i find out by looking at it?

Answer (score 1):

As it is mention in spring docs.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-resttemplate.html

> If you need to call remote REST services from your application, you can use the Spring Framework’s RestTemplate class. Since RestTemplate instances often need to be customized before being used, Spring Boot does not provide any single auto-configured RestTemplate bean. It does, however, auto-configure a RestTemplateBuilder, which can be used to create RestTemplate instances when needed. The auto-configured RestTemplateBuilder ensures that sensible HttpMessageConverters are applied to RestTemplate instances.

Answer (score 1):

As told by other users it is correct, there is no default bean defined by spring for RestTemplate. The prefered method is to use org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder  for building the rest template.

an example given below.

```
@Service
public class RestServiceCaller {

  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  RestServiceCaller(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
     restTemplate = builder.build();
  }

 ........
 .....//here you will have other methods which make use of this restTemplate
}
```

From the JavaDoc of restTemplateBuilder ->
**"In a typical auto-configured Spring Boot application this builder is available as a bean and can be injected whenever a RestTemplate is needed."**

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectMapper` works because there's other 3rd party (i.e. Jackson) code that uses that bean (and it's configured by them). You're just taking advantage of that by autowiring it to your own beans.

`RestTemplate` on the other hand isn't provided as a bean by a 3rd party in **your** codebase (it could come through a dependency). So it's up to you to create a bean of it, if you want.

You can't assume that anything is a bean unless you know it, so documentation is your first place to look.

Comment: Thanks. I found "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.ConditionalOnClass=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"
in spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties file in spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.jar. Is this what doing the autoconfigure? where can i see the list of all the auto-configured classes by springboot?

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectMapper` bean is created by Spring Boot because you have `ObjectMapper` class present in your classpath and that triggers `JacksonAutoConfiguration`. That is why you can autowire this bean without explicitly creating it.

`RestTemplate` on the other hand is a bean you have to create by yourself - Spring will not do it for you as there is not auto-configuration class that could trigger creation of it.

Comment: Thanks. I found "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.ConditionalOnClass=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"
in spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties file in spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.jar. Is this what doing the autoconfigure? where can i see the list of all the auto-configured classes by springboot?

Comment: Yes, all beans defined in that class are being created by Spring when you have `ObjectMapper` in your classpath.  You can find all auto-configuration classes here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure. You can exclude any auto-configuration class using `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {[classes to be excluded]}` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `ObjectMapper` is getting into context through a one of the cross-reerenced or transitive dependencies of you project, but the `RestTemplate` is not. So the instance of the `ObjectMapper` is creating implicitly whereas the `RestTemplate` isn't creating at all. So that is a reason you have to create a bean of the `RestTemplate` explicitly.